# ASP.NET Core Authentication : Bearer Token for an action and Windows Authentication for another in the same controller

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

What I want to do is to propose in my API different kind of endpoint that can be accessed with a Windows Authentication or JWT Bearer authentication.

### In ***Startup.cs --> Configure***, authentication is configured like this to allow Bearer authentication with desired parameters :

```
// Add JWT Bearer
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenManagement.Secret)),
        ValidIssuer = tokenManagement.Issuer,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenManagement.ClockSkewSeconds)
    };
});
```

### And to protect my endpoints i've tried something like this :

```
// THIS WAY I CAN LIMIT TO WINDOWS CREDENTIAL
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult AuthorizeWindowsUser()
{
    var user = HttpContext.User;
    if (user.GetType() == typeof(System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal))
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    return Unauthorized();
}

// THIS WAY I CAN LIMIT TO JWT
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult AuthorizeLoginUser()
{
    var user = HttpContext.User;
    if (user.GetType() == typeof(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal))
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    return Unauthorized();
}
```

### It is working, but my questions will be :

- Is it something that seems logical ? My goals is to protect the endpoints that deliver a User Token. One endpoint will be protected with a JWT Token (Refresh token) and a specific role, one will be   protected with Windows Credential.
- Am i missing something ? When i was using just Windows Authentication i used to set ***services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);*** in my **Startup.cs --> Configure** it seems that if is not necessary to work in the described implementation above but i don't really know what does this line and if it is necessary or not (btw it seems no).
- Is there a smarter/prettier way to check the type of user ? Maybe something like a custom attributes

Thanks for your advices !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems that if is not necessary to work

That's because the `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` does it for you. The method will invoke `.UseIISIntegration();` and add related services behind the scenes. For more details, see 
[Source code of invoking UseIISIntegration()](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/23596349092f69890c3efe5b8b9005856cc83db2/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L257) and [Source of UseIISIntegration() method](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/23596349092f69890c3efe5b8b9005856cc83db2/src/Servers/IIS/IISIntegration/src/WebHostBuilderIISExtensions.cs#L90).

> Is there a smarter/prettier way to check the type of user ? Maybe something like a custom attributes

You don't have to check `if( user.GetType() == typeof(System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal) {return ok;}  return Unauthorized()` manually within the action method. Use the built-in `AuthorizeAttribute` instead :

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Windows")]
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult AuthorizeWindowsUser()
{
    var user = HttpContext.User;
    if (user.GetType() == typeof(System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal))
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    return Unauthorized();
    return Ok();   // only users who are authorized with the Windows scheme can access this method
}
```

The same goes for Jwt Bearer. Since you've configured the `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` as the **default authentication scheme**, you can omit the `AuthenticationSchemes` parameter when using the `[Authorize()]` attribute annotation:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult AuthorizeLoginUser()
{
    var user = HttpContext.User;
    if (user.GetType() == typeof(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal))
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    return Unauthorized();
    return Ok();   // only users who are authorized with the default scheme can access this method
}
```

Comment: Wow, [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Windows")] was exactly what i needed, thank you very much for your answer and the explanations associated, very helping.